# Pull-to-Refresh Listview Pull on Empty View

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, pull-to-refresh

I'm using Chris Bane's "deprecated" Pull-to-Refresh library. Everything's working nicely. What I'm able to do:

1.) When there's content in the listview I can do a pull to refresh. I can see the progress dialog spinning and everything.

2.) On first load of the app if there's no data/empty listview, I can show the empty textview and I am able to do the same pull to refresh with the spinning progress bar showing.

But the second time I go to this listview (that's inside a Fragment), with empty data nothing happens. Can't do a pull to refresh -- the progress dialog doesn't show, doesn't even pull the layout. It just shows an empty text (that you can't pull anymore).

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/ptr_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="#19000000"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    app:ptrDrawable="@drawable/ic_logo_blue"
    app:ptrRotateDrawableWhilePulling="false"
    app:ptrScrollingWhileRefreshingEnabled="false"
    app:ptrHeaderBackground="#EEEEEE"
    app:ptrRefreshableViewBackground="#F7F7F7"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/emptyView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Empty list"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

I also tried replacing the RelativeLayout with LinearLayout, but the issue still exists.

**Additional Info**

Not sure if these are relevant:

- The Fragment that contains the listview is inside a SlidingTab
- The listview reference to the pull to refresh listview has a height of 0.

Here's the code to the Fragment's onCreateView()

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    result = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, container, false);
    listView = (PullToRefreshListView)result.findViewById(R.id.directoryList);
    emptyTextView = (TextView)result.findViewById(R.id.emptyEventsView);
    adapter =  new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_item, someList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setEmptyView(emptyTextView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    listView.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    listView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            listView.setRefreshing();
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Sorry for the long post. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you try the google provided SwipeRefreshLayout??

Comment: I needed a custom views to show in the header (where the progress dialog shows).

Comment: Also, I already implemented SwipeRefreshLayout, initially and it wasn't approved by our designer.